# As’ meaning in this sentence

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

> Baby, baby, feels like maybe, things will be all right Baby, baby,
>   your love's made me Free as a song, singin' forever

This is a part of my favorite song, “only yesterday” by carpenters. And I am not sure how “as” means in this sentence. I guess it is the same as  “like” and the last sentence means I am free like a song and l will sing forever. Is my understanding correct?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea. Either *as* or *like* can be used for a comparison; this figure of speech is called a [simile](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/simile)

> : a figure of speech comparing two unlike things that is often introduced by like or as (as in cheeks like roses)

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand the usage.